# Is there any difference between “anstatt” and “statt”?

Tags: difference

Is it just your own choice of words or do they (*anstatt* and *statt*) also mean two different things?

Comment: No difference between the two.

Comment: Basically no difference, though I would second the sentiment expressed by "Glockenblume" here: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/anstatt-statt.2768344/

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch?

Comment: @userunknown Wörterbücher sagen haufig nicht zu viel...

Comment: Can you add an example? Why do you think the two word mean the same or do not?

Comment: I thought people use one as a preposition(with genitiv) and the other one as conjunction(to connect 2 sentences). But appearently they are exact the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If we look at the etymology of *[statt](https://www.dwds.de/wb/statt)* we can see that it is a shortened form for *[anstatt](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anstatt)*:

> **statt**  *Präp. Konj.*   (17. Jh.), aus **anstatt** gekürzt. Dazu statt daß, statt zu (18. Jh.).<sup>[Etymologisches Wörterbuch (nach Pfeifer)](https://www.dwds.de/wb/statt)</sup>

Both have the same meaning and usage until today. When using the unshortened form we may intend a higher register of German but in this case this is of not much siginficance.

Please note that both, *statt*, and *anstatt* go with genitive case which increasingly gets lost in colloquial speech.

Comment: _... using the unshortened form we may intend a higher register..._: looking at the [examples](https://www.dwds.de/wb/statt) I wouldn't say so, to me it sounds more the other way round. It may be also worth noting that the frequent collocation _statt dessen_ only works with _statt_.

Answer (score 0):

Basically 'statt' is used for same sort of quantities like tea or coffee; shoes or socks; jeans or t-shirts. 
For eg. Statt schlafende, möchte Ich schuhe. (I prefer wearing shoes over slipper.)

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. unfortunately I think your answer has a spelling error on the german example. Please provide also the use of "anstatt" in your knowledge

Comment: I admit that this distinction sounds interesting. However, I have never heard of it before. Could you add a source, please?