# Gebrauchsunterschied zwischen statt, anstatt und anstelle

Tags: difference, preposition, conjunction

Was unterscheidet statt vs. anstatt vs. anstelle **anhand der folgenden Beispiele?**
Können statt und anstatt beliebig verwendet werden, ohne jeglichen Bedeutungsunterschied? 
Die Frage bezüglich des Paares "statt vs. anstatt" wurde schon mal gestellt, wurde aber nicht ausführlich und eindeutig beantwortet; außerdem wurde damals das dritte Wort "anstelle" nicht mit einbezogen.

Beispiele:

1. »Wenn der Anpassungsprozeß erfolgt ist, zeigt sich in Wirklichkeit, daß das Gehirn des Arbeiters, anstatt zu veröden, einen Zustand völliger Freiheit erreicht hat.
2. Die intensive Selbstanalyse isoliert, anstatt zu vereinen.
3. Aber anstatt zu sinken, saßen wir auf dem Ufer fest.
4. Du hast mir vorgeworfen, ich hätte die Mentalität eines Nazis; nur, weil ich die Nazis bekämpft habe, statt zu jammern.
5. Fragen beantwortet sie deshalb am liebsten selber, statt zu dolmetschen.
6. Statt zu zahlen, erhält die Familie der Frau Geld und wertvolle Gegenstände.
7. Statt zu sprechen oder zuzuhören, schaltet man lieber das Fernsehen oder Radio ein oder vertieft sich in eine Zeitung oder Zeitschrift.
8. Statt seiner Repräsentation brauchen sie sein Maß und seine Photographie.
9. Bisher hat man das Feuer in Laos geschürt anstatt es zu löschen.
10. Statt seiner Tochter das Posten von Selfies zu verbieten, hat ihr Vater eine wirklich lustige Idee.
11. Anstatt seiner Tochter dankbar zu sein, schlug ein 54-Jähriger gestern Nachmittag auf die 24-Jährige ein.
12. Doch statt seiner Tochter findet er ein anderes Mädchen – tot.
13. Statt seiner Tochter fand er ein ganz hässliches Mädchen darin.
14. Aber statt/anstelle/anstatt der Leiterin ist der CEO zum Meeting gekommen.
15. Die Truppen der UN im Kongo paradieren nur, statt daß sie uns beider Evakuation der feindlichen belgischen Streitkräfte behilflich sind.
16. Anstelle/statt/anstatt des Buches kaufte ich ihr Blumen.

Comment: Die Frage bezüglich des Paares "statt vs. anstatt" wurde schon mal gestellt, wurde aber nicht ausführlich und eindeutig beantwortet; außerdem wurde damals das dritte Wort "anstelle" nicht mit einbezogen.
Darüber hinaus habe ich die Beispiele so ausgesucht, dass sich die Frage besser antworten lässt, was bei der vorherigen Frage nicht der Fall war.

Comment: Was genau ist dir bei der anderen Antwort nicht klar? anstelle ist einfach ein Synonym zu anstatt.

Comment: what about https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/52994/difference-between-statt-and-anstelle/53003 ?

Comment: "*Bisher hat man das Feuer in Laos geschürt anstatt es zu löschen.*" Might be a most relevant example, if *anstatt* is akin to an unironic *Anstalten machen* (not *to block*, but *to set up for, attempt to*). It might read *fire was fueled in (order to / stead of) getting it under control*, which invariably would sound ironic. *statthaft* means *meating the dead line* , possibly *orderly*. Voting reopen to clear this up.

Comment: @idmean, kein Synonym ist einfach! 
Es gibt fast immer WICHTIGE aber für Muttersprachler unauffälige Gebrauchsunterschiede, vgl. anbieten und bieten. Daher ist es wichtig, dass auch auf "anstelle" dabei eingegangen wird.
Darüber hinaus fehlt bei der Antwort die stylistische Erläuterung. Ein Kommentator vertritt sogar eine ganz andere Meinung https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41336/is-there-any-difference-between-anstatt-and-statt#comment120111_41339 
And it makes perfect sense to have this question answered in an detailed way, once and for all and mit Bezug auf ALLE DREI Synonyme.

Comment: @Dan die Fragestellung unterscheidet sich in der Hinsicht aber kaum von der anderen, die daher auch keine besseren Antworten motiviert, wenngleich deine Biespiele sublime Details andeuten mögen